# How to sort Employee data, based on department count

Tags: sql-server

I have EMP table..
Eno Ename Salary deptmentid
101 Alex   2000    10

Like this I have data of 1000 employees, with 23 different departments..Now my requirement is to sort the data in such way that, which department has highest no. of employee..

For example dept-50 has 45 employees(highest in all departments) , then these 45 employees should be listed first. Dept-12 has 3 employees, then these 3 employees should be listed last in the employ table..

Comment: Get those CVs out. I think a career move is requied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Eno, Ename, Salary, E.deptmentid
FROM EMP E INNER JOIN 
                (SELECT deptmentid, COUNT(Ename) TotalEmps  
                FROM EMP 
                GROUP BY deptmentid) Sub
ON E.deptmentid = Sub.deptmentid
ORDER BY TotalEmps DESC
```

Comment: I have one more question, cant I use "distinct" , while I am joining 3 tables??

Comment: @user3116746 yes you can always use Distinct no matter how many tables you are joining to, it will return only the distinct values. and if the answer helped you please accept the answer :)

Comment: Is it not possible Row_Number() and distinct both in Query?

Comment: well when you use ROW_NUMBER function all the rows will be assigned a distinct row number and you will always get all the rows back, so it doesnt make much sense to use it with ROW_NUMBER() .

Comment: Ok. But, Kindly let me know, My qurey is resulted 1000 different rows(based on several conditions and Joins). In this result table I need to add a Column with SNo(Serial Number)..How to do this??

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

```
Declare @Emp table ( Eno int, Ename varchar(50), Salary int, deptmentid int )

insert into @Emp values(1,'cvxcv',3,45),(2,'uyyudfdf',3,45),(3,'hhgcvxcv',3,45),(4,'wewecvxcv',3,46)
,(5,'sscvxcv',3,46),(6,'nmmcvxcv',3,47),(7,'erewr',3,47)

select *,dense_rank()over(order by deptmentid)rn from @Emp
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, count(*) over (partition by departmentmentid) as DepartmentCount
      from emp e
     ) e
order by DepartmentCount desc, DepartmentId;
```

Note the sort by DepartmentId as well as the count.  If two departments have the same count, then this will keep the employees together by department.

You also might like:

```
select e.*, row_number() over (partition by departmentid order by newid()) as CounterInDepartment
. . .
```

This enumerates the employees within each department.

Answer (score 0):

```
select employee.name, employee.job, employee.deptmentid, 
    count(*)  over(partition by deptmentid) as [count]
 from EMPLOYEE
 order by [count] desc, deptmentid
```